# Create a query that shows work you planned at the beginning of a sprint

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking to create a query that shows all of the stories that were added to the sprint during our sprint planning meeting. This meeting always takes place on day 1 of the sprint.

Naturally, some stories may be removed mid-sprint but I'd still like to see what was originally planned.

Equally, some stories may be added mid-sprint and I wouldn't want to include those.

I noticed that the built-in Velocity widget has a 'planned' bar, but I'm not entirely sure how that's calculated.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue ,deleted work items cannot be displayed with other work items in queries. If you want to query the stories created by a certain period of time, you can do it in two steps.

First you can query the stories created in the initial time period by the following conditions.

[image]

Then you can add the **Created Date** and **Iteration Path** column in **Recycle Bin** to find the stories deleted in this time period.

[image]

[image]

If your stories are permanently deleted(Remove from Recycle Bin), then you will really cannot query them.